# Abel transformable flat-top function

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, functions, definite-integrals

I am looking for an even function that has flat profile at $r=0$ and relatively flat to some value of $r$ and then drops down to nearly zero.
It is similar to the graph below, where it drops around $r=5$.

[image: flat-top function]

The function also needs to be integrable in Abel transformation:
$$
g(y) = 2\int_y^\infty \frac{f(r)\ r}{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}}\ \mathrm{d}r.
$$

I tried a super gaussian function which has profile of
$$
f(r) = \exp\left[-(r/r_i)^{2n}\right],
$$
where $n$ is a positive integer and $r_i$ is a variable to set where the function value is dropped down. I tried to insert the function into Abel transformation, but I stuck at the integral below:
$$
g(y) = 2 n r_i \int_a^\infty x^{n-1} \exp\left(-x^n\right)\sqrt{x-a}\ \mathrm{d}x,
$$
where $a = (y/r_i)^2$.

If you know a function that has similar profile with the graph above and it can be integrated analytically in Abel transformation, that would be great!
Any hints and helps are appreciated.